# Unity's Quaternion.Lerp slows down when target is directly behind turret

Tags: unity, quaternion, lerp

Software: Unity v5.2.1f1 Personal

I am trying to achieve the effect of a turret in Unity. For this I have a turret consisting of 3 parts as well as a target. The problem is that whenever the target my turret is targeting has a z of < 0, the lerp *speed* is extremely slow. However, the further away the target is from x=0 (both positive and negative), the faster it will move. This effect only occurs when my target has a transform.position.z of < 0. When z > 0 the transform.position.x has no effect on the lerp *speed*. My setup is as follows:

The 3 turret parts are the **base**, **turret** and **barrel**.

The **base** is nothing more than a block for the **turret** to rest on. 
The **turret** is a block holding the barrel in place with **base** as his parent. The **turret** rotates around its *y-axis* to always face the target. The **barrel** has **turret** as his parent. The **barrel** rotates around its *x-axis* to always face the target. See the picture below for the end result.

*Base: Blue; Turret: Red; Barrel: Green;*
[image: Turret Rundown]

The **turret** has the following code:

```
public class turretRotation : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 relativePosition = target.position - transform.position;
        relativePosition.y = 0;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePosition, new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.localRotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

The **barrel** has the following code:

```
public class barrelRotation : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;
    public float speed = 1;
    Vector3 relPos;
    Quaternion rot;

    void Update () {
        // Position of target relative to my position
        relPos = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;

        rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(relPos, new Vector3(0,1,0));

        // Lerping localRotatiot > rot with speed: Time.deltaTime * speed (set to 1 by default)
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.localRotation, rot, Time.deltaTime *  speed);

        // Resetting y- and z-EulerAngles to 0; This way only the x-EulerAngle will be affected. 
        // The y rotation is inherited from the parent (turret_turret)
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.localEulerAngles.x, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

*In this picture the Lerp is working as intended; Note target.transform.z > 0*
[image: working as intended]

*In this picture the target has a z = -5 and x = 0; pay particular attention to the Lerp speed*
[image: very slow!]

It eventually gets there, but it takes a *very* long time. For some reason, the further away the target is from x=0, the faster the Lerp speed. *Note: Still slower than intended*

*In this picture the target has a z = -5 and x = -10*
[image: Slightly better but not quite]

So for some reason when target.transform.z has a negative value, the higher the distance from target.transform.x to x=0 the higher the Lerp *speed*.

I've done a fair bit of searching and came across a post on answers.unity.com describing a similair problem; Unfortunately, no reply. 
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1084067/lerp-problem-when-target-is-behind.html

**So my question is: "Why is this happening and more importantly, how can I fix this?"**

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Because it depends on distance, there might be something wrong with normalization - maybe re-phrasing the code(using temp variable, or Normalize() instead of .normalized) would help?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've tried using Vector3.Normalize() instead of .normalized, but to no avail. I am not sure what you mean with using temp variables though. Could you further clarify? Again thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Assigning the result (loc-target) to local variable, normalizing it on next line, just to be super-safe the issue is not normalization.

Comment: Ah, I've tried it, but unfortunately the problem still persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at your barrel rotation function...

```
relPos = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(relPos, new Vector3(0,1,0));
```

`relPos` is in world space, so `rot` is an absolute rotation (ie. relative to the *world coordinate frame*)

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(
      transform.localRotation, 
      rot,
      Time.deltaTime *  speed);
```

transform.localRotation is relative to the *parent's coordinate space*.

**So this Lerp is blending between a relative orientation and an absolute one**.

When you use Lerp this way, the speed or increment each frame is proportional to the difference between the start & end values. (This adds a nice bit of slowing as the rotation approaches the target compared to `Quaternion.RotateTowards()` which enforces a particular speed)

Assuming your barrel is already pointing somewhat near your target...

- When the parent's rotation is very similar to the world coordinate frame, the difference between transform.localRotation and rot will tend to be small (slow tracking).
- When the parent's is rotated a lot relative to the world coordinate frame, the difference between transform.localRotation and rot will tend to be very large (fast tracking).

So you'll want to make sure you're using apples-to-apples comparisons when Lerping - either work entirely in local space (eg. with `transform.parent.InverseTransformDirection(relPos)` or `Quaternion.Inverse(transform.parent.rotation)` ) or entirely in world space.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and thorough explanation. I understand my mistake and I added the line relPos = transform.parent.InverseTransformDirection(relPos);. It works perfectly now. Again, thank you very much.